# express Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express

I am trying to do a get request but it keeps failing on `app.js` `res.json` line.

**app.js**

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get("env") === "development" ? err : {};

  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.json({ error: err.message });
});
```

**model**

```
const fs = require("fs");
const fileName = "./seatData.json";
const file = require(fileName);

const Seat = function(seat) {
  this.seat = seat.seat;
  this.seatNumber = seat.seatNumber;
  this.price = seat.price;
  this.available = seat.available;
  this.disabilityAccessible = seat.disabilityAccessible;
};

Seat.findSeat = seatNumber => {
  return file.find(obj => obj.seatNumber === seatNumber);
};

Seat.getSeatByNumber = function(seatNumber, result) {
  this.seat = this.findSeat(seatNumber);
  if (Object.keys(this.seat).length > 0) {
    result(null, this.seat);
  } else {
    result({ error: true, message: "Seat not found" });
  }
};

Seat.bookSeat = function(seatNumber, result) {
  this.seat = this.findSeat(seatNumber);
  if (this.seat === undefined || Object.keys(this.seat).length === 0) {
    result({ error: true, message: "Seat not found" });
  }
  const newSeatData = file.map(row => {
    if (row.seatNumber === seatNumber) {
      row.available = false;
      this.seat = row;
    }
    return row;
  });
  fs.writeFile("./seatData.json", newSeatData, "utf-8", function(err) {
    if (err) {
      result({ error: true, message: "failed to update booking" });
    }
  });

  result(null, this.seat);
};

module.exports = Seat;
```

route

```
router.get(
  "/bookSeat/:seatNumber",
  [
    check("seatNumber")
      .exists(true)
      .withMessage("Must pass seatNumber")
      .matches(/^[0-9][a-z]$/i)
      .withMessage("must start with a number(0-9) and end with a letter")
  ],
  actions.update_seat
);
```

**controller**

```
exports.update_seat = (req, res) => {
  const errors = validationResult(req);
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    res.status(422).json({ error: true, message: errors.array() });
  }
  console.log(errors);
  Seat.bookSeat(req.params.seatNumber, (err, seat) => {
    if (err) res.json(err);
    else res.json(seat);
  });
};
```

I am trying to call `bookSeat`  https://codesandbox.io/s/elucidate-api-fokd8

Comment: Thats because an error occurs in a route endpoint *after you sent data to the client*. Could you show us the relevant route?

Comment: updated with route

Comment: What is `actions.update_seat` ?

Comment: updated with controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After an error occured, you still go on with execution:

```
 if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
  res.status(422).json({ error: true, message: errors.array() });
  return; // <<!!
 }
```

Comment: do i need to do this for all errors in the controller. i get same problem for all of them. what is difference when i do `if (err) res.json(err);` it does not fail then

Comment: Its an if..else.

Comment: if i comment out `res.json({ error: err.message });` in app.js it works but the return did not change the failure

Comment: Then there is something writing to `res` that younhaven't shown yet, but the problem is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Before

```
const login =async(req,res)=>{
  let {username,password}=req.body;
  console.log(username,password);
var token = jwt.sign({ username:username}, 'ok');
  if(!username)
{
  res.send('No USer Name')
}
else{

  res.send(`<h1> Secret Token is=>  ${token}  ${token}</h1>`)   //line 10
}
     res.send('login/register/signup')  // line 12
}
```

there can be reason where programmer have use res.send more than one so just avoid that thing ,

After

```
const login =async(req,res)=>{
  let {username,password}=req.body;
  console.log(username,password);
var token = jwt.sign({ username:username}, 'ok');
  if(!username)
{
  res.send('No USer Name')
}
else{

  res.send(`<h1> Secret Token is=>  ${token}  ${token}</h1>`)
}
    // res.send('login/register/signup')  comm
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### I think it's a straightforward and common issue.

> This error occurs if you are trying to send multiple `HTTP` responses.

### **Are you thinking about how we can fix this issue?**
LOL, okay don't worry, I'll tell you how you can fix it.

- If you are sending responses in a loop.
- Then make sure that you exit the loop after sending the response.
- You can use the `return` statement to exit the loop and prevent any further responses from being sent.

> Let's take an example, how we can do this.

```
if (!username || !password) return res.status(400).json({ message: "Username & Password required!" });
```